# Selenium JAVA xPath Firefox vs Internet Explorer

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, cross-browser

I am working with the RemoteWebDriver, Firefox the Selenium IDE and JAVA.

From the start I run the IDE to check and debug the web page. I got an xpath the value like this using the IDE:

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "/url?value=something");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//li[@onclick='menu.open(this)'])[4]")).click();
```

...using JAVA with RemoteWebDriver and findElementByPath(...) or findElement(By.xpath(...)) I got the exception:

EXCEPTION: Unable to find element with xpath == (//li[@onclick='menu.open(this)'])[4]

I played with the value and try those by IDE and by JAVA:

```
    (//li[@onclick='menu.open(this)'])[4]
    and
    //li[@onclick='menu.open(this)'][4]
```

With IDE it works with JAVA not...

**Update and correction!**

I modified the test program to use Firefox instead IE (Version 11) and it works. What is the different handling in using xpath with IE and Firefox? Or more generally which browser works with xpath in which way and the same value?

**Update**

The page is running in IE Version 7 mode. May this causes the trouble?!?

Comment: It could be that the IDE is waiting for the element to appear, whereas your Java program is not. Have you tried adding a wait for the element?

Comment: Hi Ben. 

I think not, see my update. The xpath is on the current page and it's active. I make a screenshot of them before I try to use xpath...

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML on IE?  It's very possible that the HTML is different on IE as compared to Firefox.  That "[4]" at the end of the path is a strong possibility...perhaps there are fewer of these list items in IE?

Comment: Hi BS. Hard to compare... The structure view of the page between IE debugger and FF debugger is different but the count and content of the elements is the same... A work around could be using findElement(By.id(...)), but it is just a work around for this case...

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the Link may it can help you 
[IE X-Path](http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2015/07/how-to-run-selenium-webdriver-test.html)

Comment: Hi QATesting. The IE works proper as long as I am not using xpath. The program starts the main page, switch to a second window and logon and logoff by findElement(By.name) and by findElement(By.id) works fine. Just xpath (for the moment) is not working in same like Firefox...